# Live video encoding using...?

Tags: .net, ffmpeg, webcam, directshow, encode

I'm attempting to write a fairly simplistic application that will stream video/audio from a webcam to someone else across the internet (ala Skypebut with more control).

There seems to be very little useful/relevant information on the subjectand what I can find is largely outdated. From my research so far, [x264 seems to be the way to go](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/249) as it offers an `ultrafast` option which is designed for this situation

I'm able to turn on the webcam and receive a stream of images. I can also listen on an audio device and get samples.

Where I'm failing is encoding that information in such a way as to be able to stream with a minimum of latency (from what I've read, 200ms delay is the goal for no obvious lag, including network latency - so let's aim for 100-150ms)

Things I've tried

#### ffmpeg

This seems to be the most widely used option for encoding. I've had two real issues using it. Firstly, even using x264 with no look-aheads and the bare minimum buffers for stability, the delay seems to be on the order of 700ms using image2pipe. Secondly, it requires ffmpeg to be installed - being able to do this without an external dependency would be nice.

#### VLC

As with ffmpeg this requires an external program which is a negative. Even worse, I can't seem to get a latency of under 2 seconds which seems to increase over time. I've also only been able to get VLC to capture the camera itself rather than take a stream of images which means I don't get a chance to pre-process them.

#### DirectShow

I've seen a number of sites recommending using the windows direct show encoders but I haven't been able to find one that works at anything like real time. In fact, the only one I've managed to get going reliably is a Windows Media codec that has a massive latency and fairly large size.

#### Other considerations

None of the above address the problem of adding an audio stream to the video. I'm not sure if I should attempt to encode them together or send a separate stream alongside the video.

In short, I've been Googling for a week or so now and haven't found a decent way to do this. Can someone please point me at a decent example/guide?

Comment: _Can someone please point me at a decent example/guide?_ With a reputation of 11.3k I'd hardly expect to have to point you at [help/on-topic], Point 5.

Comment: @MikeW This is a very specific question with specific answers, and is very much on-topic for Stack Overflow.  The "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource" rule is not intended for well thought out questions like this.

Comment: @Basic DirectShow is built for what you are trying to do, and is the way to go for capture, and maybe even encoding.  You should know though that 200ms delay is insanely low and I don't think you'll find any software off the shelf that does this today.  Skype does low latency the best I've seen, and its delay feels around 500ms just for video capture.  Try this out with Skype to see if there isn't an extra delay added by your camera and drivers already.  Even 200ms latency for audio capture isn't reasonable without DirectShow, ASIO, or WinMM.

Comment: @Basic What sort of pre-processing do you need to do?  What platforms do you need to support?  Depending on what you need, all of the heavy lifting may be already done by Chrome and Firefox if you want to make this a web application.  WebRTC was built for low-latency video chat, and there are several ways to process the video.

Comment: Some hints: DirectShow is API, you can find various encoders, including simpler like Motion JPEG running with minimal latency and no temporal compression, "frame in - frame out". Talking about DirectShow your question should be "what encoder should I use, I would like to have it with DirectShow interface". Similar applies to other. Your stab was to get H.264 video, and `x264` is one of the best encoders out there. You either tune to it reduce latency, or look for another encoder.

Comment: Another note is that good capture hardware captures at latencies on the order of 100 ms on its own. Then your encoding (let's assume it's zero and we don't compress temporally), then network transmission, then buffering to achieve smooth playback. This adds up into overall latency.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply... Christmas. That's a goal and I accept I might not be able to hit 200ms but you have to start aiming somewhere. Re: pre-processing, none other than (say) allowing me to add an overlay. Re: Platforms I'm only aiming for Win7+ - this isn't for public consumption. I'm already using DShow for capture (indirectly). Skype's latency feels (anecdotally) less than 500ms to me - but perhaps that's simply that the audio is faster so the brain allows for slow video. That at least is a clear hint I should handle audio separately.

Comment: @Brad thanks for the suggestion re: WinRTC I hadn't considered that and it might do well enough that I can avoid this issue entirely. I'll look into it

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks for the info, I hadn't realised hardware was so slow capturing. I'll have a go at H264 again and see if I'm making some obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use x264vfw via either DirectShow or even Video for Windows. This codec has "zero latency" option where it basically works in "frame in - frame out" mode. I described how I reduced x264 encoding latency in a DirectShow app [here](http://www.infognition.com/blog/2012/writing_avi_files_x264.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting but doesn't actually give any detail on how to configure the encoder - just describing how you used graphedit to examine the output from the encoder...

Comment: This is a VfW codec, it has a standard way to open its settings dialog, in DirectShow that is IAMVfwCompressDialogs interface. In that dialog those settings are set.